# Echo a value of XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I want the to echo the `<version>`-tag from the URL: http://marketplaceedgeservice.windowsphone.com/v3.2/en-us/apps?q=ctrlbase&chunksize=50&clientType=WinMobile%208.0

How to do that in PHP?

Comment: Since you are looking at an xml document, it's advisable to use an xml reader such as simplexml: http://us3.php.net/simplexml

Answer (score 0):

Split all the text into two parts using explode.

```
$FirstArray = explode("<version>", $string);
```

Then again split the remaining content into two parts

```
$SecondArray = explode("</version>", $FirstArray[1]);
```

Then you will have the text inside the version  tag in the array $SecondArray.

Just 
    echo $SecondArray[0];

Comment: downvoted because although it works (only temporarily), it only teaches the person asking the question to hack their way through things instead of choosing the best method for scalability and not needing updates in the future, etc.. what if the xml is updated tomorrow to read <version docurl='http://docs.whatever.com/docs.xml'>1.0</version>

Comment: Sorry. I just wanted to tell him what I know. And you are correct. It is not a good way though it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using simplexml_load_string you should be able to convert the returned sting into an object in PHP that you can access normally by its associated key value pair. There is a good example here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php.

However it looks like there is an error in the xml returned, I would verify that is correct when parsing it.

More Detail on Simplexml https://www.php.net/simplexml